# How to Set the Line Item value in loop on the client Script suitescript 1.0?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript1.0

```
  var LineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
  var RepairJob  = '167543';
    for(var i=1;i<=LineCount;i++){
        var RepairJobLink = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', "custcol_advs_repair_task_link",i);
        var InvType = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', "custcol_advs_selected_inventory_type",i);
        if(InvType != 3 && (RepairJobLink == RepairJob)){
          nlapiSetLineItemValue("item", "custcol_advs_repair_task_link", i,135895); 
          nlapiSetLineItemValue("item", "custcol_advs_fa_org_lab", i,"33445566"); //
        }
       
    }
```

here Value: "33445566" for the field "custcol_advs_fa_org_lab" is working since it is a text field
but for the "custcol_advs_repair_task_link", its not setting the value ;

Comment: The only thing I could advise is to try to do it manually in a web browser, first. If it's possible and the value is set — then dig deeper here, if it's not set — than dig in that direction